# Using quotes in a text you publish under creative commons

Tags: fair-use

Fair use allows quoting other texts (or images) as part of your text, but how does this interact with you publishing the work under a creative commons license that allows derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst writing this question I actually found the answer (emphasis mine):

> ## May I apply a CC license to my work if it incorporates material used under fair use or another exception or limitation to copyright?
>
> Yes, but it is important to **prominently mark any third party material** you incorporate into your work so reusers do not think the CC license applies to that material. The CC license only applies to the rights you have in the work. **For example**, if your CC-licensed slide deck includes a Flickr image you are using pursuant to fair use, **make sure to identify that** image **as not being subject to the CC license**. [For more information about incorporating work owned by others, see our page about marking third party content.](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Marking/Creators/Marking_third_party_content)

[Source: Copyright by creativecommons.org licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International license](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#may-i-apply-a-cc-license-to-my-work-if-it-incorporates-material-used-under-fair-use-or-another-exception-or-limitation-to-copyright)